# Filtering between FROM and TO dates in HTML table using datetimepicker in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, datetime, html-table

I have a table that consists of date logs (with time included). I want to use a datetimepicker so that I can filter a FROM date and TO date which should return a filtered table filled with all date time logs between the chosen dates. How can I do this?

**Example:**

If I choose:

```
FROM: 2020/01/04 15:40
TO: 2020/01/05 18:40
```

it should give me filtered records in HTML table between selected dates.

This is what I had done so far:

**interface.html:**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    $(function(){  
        $("#from_date").datetimepicker();  
        $("#to_date").datetimepicker();  
    });  
    $('#search').click(function(){  
        var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
        var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
        if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
        {    
            var filter, table, tr, td, i;
            filter = date.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                    if (td) {
                        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
            else  
            {  
                alert("Please Select Date");  
            }  
       });  
    }


<input name="from_date" id="from_date" type="text" placeholder="From date..."> 
<input name="to_date" id="to_date" type="text" placeholder="To date...">
<button name="search" id="search" value="search"> Search </button>

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> From date </th>
            <th> To date </th> 
            <th> Daily Time </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='time_details'>
        <tr>
            <td> 04-01-2020 12:14:15 PM </td>
            <td> 05-01-2020 12:14:15 PM </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 07-01-2020 09:30:00 AM </td>
            <td> 09-01-2020 11:00:00 PM </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 20-01-2020 08:00:00 PM </td>
            <td> 21-01-2020 11:00:00 PM </td>
        </tr>      
    </tbody>

</table>
```

How can I filter the rows in a table using datetimepicker? Can anyone please help me with the Javascript code above?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the TD contents into a moment object? Not sure what the exact issue is you're having problems with.

Comment: I am not able to filter the table rows when the From and To dates are used. How do you parse the TD contents into the moment object?

Comment: Your current code doesn't appear to actually use `from_date` and `to_date`. And parsing should be as simple as `const tdDate = moment(td.textContent);`, provided momentjs supports parsing that datetime format.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much for the solution, but I am just a beginner in Javascript. Can you please demonstrate a small example on how to do this with my existing code?

Comment: Alright, here's working code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lqoeubrt/

Comment: @ChrisG Hello, I am not able to filter the dates from suppose 9:00AM to a certain date. If I mention a specific date filtration, then it outputs nothing back. I am only able to output details between an hour. How can I filter records between 9:00 am and 17:00 pm even though there are only records between 9:00 am and 14:00 pm?

Comment: The filtering in my example only shows timespans that are fully inside the chosen two points of time. Do you want to display anything that overlaps the chosen range instead?